# Parent an empty to an animated geometry node object

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, parent, empty

I would like to parent an empty to the glass of a window created and animated procedurally. Unfortunately I know really little about geometry nodes and I don't understand how I could parent an exterior object to one specific part of a procedural object.
A simple "copy location" system would be great.

Could you help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: Short answer: Unfortunately you can't do that. ...at least not as long as your mesh created with *Geometry Nodes* shall remain procedural. The geometry created with *Geometry Nodes* is created like any other modifier at the end of the chain. But your Empty exists before and has no access to parameters/meshes generated later by modifiers.

Comment: can you please tell us your end goal? I think it is possible what you want, but not via "empty" - but you could instead move the object "directly"

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your help. I managed to figure it out myself. I just used a system of drivers to connect the rotation of one of my geometry node to the rotation of my empty. It was simpler I would have expected.